How to change the default behavior of a function permanently?
For example, I want the function Animate to work with options AnimationRepetitions -> 1, AppearanceElements -> "ResetButton" by default such that I don't have to type there options each time I call Animate.  What should I do?

Have you tried to use SetOptions?

I'm new to mathematica and don't know SetOptions. I'll search the document and thanks for your hint.

@lericr I tried, but it only works for the current notebook.

This should not happen, how do you use SetOptions? Or you actually mean "current session" by "current notebook" i.e. you've restarted Mathematica? If so, you need to put the line in SystemOpen@"init.m" file.

@xzczd I see. Thank you.
